# Best practice for applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: iphone, nsnotification

I am in the middle of writing an application that needs to reset certain parts of its state to a default state when the application calls applicationDidEnterBackground. What I would like to know is if it is a better practice to get a pointer to the view that needs to be reset and then reset the properties that need to be reset right there in the app delegate, or should I post an NSNotification that the app is entering the background and have the view controller do it's cleanup within itself. Or maybe there's another method I'm not thinking of.

I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These notifications get posted already. Just subscribe to the event in your controller class(es) and do whatever you need to there.

From the docs:

> The application also posts a
>   UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
>   notification around the same time it
>   calls this method to give interested
>   objects a chance to respond to the
>   transition.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification

Comment: Thanks very much! I was kinda thinking notification would be the best practice here, and didn't know there was a system notification already there!